# Delphi Form Restored State Position and Size

Tags: delphi, winapi

In a maximized delphi form, how to get form's restored state position and size? I know in .NET we use `RestoreBounds` and `DesktopBound`.

Comment: You can use JediVCL library, where there are `TJvFormPlacement` and `TJvFormStorage` components that automatically save/restore form's bounds to/from registry, ini or DB

Answer (score 7):

This is not exposed by the VCL framework. Instead you need to dip into the Win32 API. The function you need is [`GetWindowPlacement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633518.aspx).

```
var
  WindowPlacement: TWindowPlacement;
....
WindowPlacement.length := SizeOf(WindowPlacement);
Win32Check(GetWindowPlacement(Form.Handle, WindowPlacement));
```

The information you need can be found in the `WindowPlacement` struct. Do beware that the coordinates are reported with respect to the work area rather than the screen.

Generally you want this information so that you can restore it at a later date. Use `SetWindowPlacement` to do that.

Comment: A simple `get` and `set` work if you always have the same number of monitors.  If you `get` while on a monitor that you later unplug, then `set` back to the saved values, your app will appear off-screen.  The JVCL tests to make sure the `WindowPlacement.rcNormalPosition` is on-screen before it does a `SetWindowPlacement` (see JvJVCLUtils.pas `InternalRestoreFormPlacement`).